# Aguegar campo "Hora > FiscalMonth" en archivo PBIX del ejemplo de Análisis de minoristas

Tags: powerbi, microsoft

[Creación de visualizaciones de indicador clave de rendimiento (KPI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-kpi?tabs=powerbi-desktop)
En el 1er link hay un pequeño tutorial para aprender a ocupar KPIs en power BI.
Te pide descargar el siguiente archivo si ocupas la opción power bi desktop:
[archivo PBIX del ejemplo de Análisis de minoristas](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/6/D/96DDC2FF-2568-491D-AAFA-AFDD6F763AE3/Retail%20Analysis%20Sample%20PBIX.pbix)

Cuando empieza la parte **Cómo crear un KPI**, en el 2. dice "2. Agregue Hora>FiscalMonth. Este valor representará la tendencia."

Mi pregunta es, como hacer eso ya que buscando en los campos no veo una opción ni columna que diga "FiscalMonth" ?